# Does the required cooling energy increase when Quantum computer processors with more and more entangled Qubits are produced?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

IBM has succeeded in 2021 in realizing a Quantum computer with 127 entangled Qubits (Processor Eagle). A Quantum computer with 433 entangled Qubits (Processor Osprey) was planned for 2022, and a Quantum computer with 1121 entangled Qubits (Processor Condor) for 2023.

Does the required cooling energy increase as Quantum computer processors with more and more entangled Qubits are produced? Has anyone ever thought to measure this (could have broad implications)?

Comment: you might also try asking this on https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get answers here (if you do, please either delete this one, or add links connecting the two versions of the question)

Comment: Dear glS, In the meantime I have also contacted IBM directly, so my strategy is to wait maybe an additional 2 weeks for potential feedback, before posting this modest question (with possibly broad implications) elsewhere. In any case, thanks for your advice. With best regards

Comment: you don't have to, it's your choice, of course. As a brief comment, energy cost of cooling is certainly something that people in the field are conscious about, but I can't think of a paper studying explicitly that right now. Considering that we're still far from building devices that are useful for practical applications (well, I should say arguably I suppose; some would argue otherwise) people generally focus on managing to build the things regardless of energy costs for now. Optimisation seems like an issue to worry about once there is *some* way to build the devices in the first place

Comment: UPDATE (from additional feedback received): It can be expected that the contribution of the synergistic effect of maximum Quantum entanglement is completely negligible compared to all technical sources which obviously lead to an increase in the required cooling energy. IBM, Google and others may not have been able so far to detect the synergistic effect of maximum Quantum entanglement (increasing with the number of entangled Qubits), since their Quantum computers still have a limited number of entangled Qubits (previously 5, 50 and now up to 433 entangled Qubits e.g. IBM Processor Osprey).

Comment: UPDATE (continued): A Quantum computer with 1121 entangled Qubits (Processor Condor) is planned by IBM for 2023, with 1326+ entangled Qubits (Processor Flamingo) for 2024, with 4158+ entangled Qubits (Processor Kookaburra) for 2025 and scaling up to 10k-100k entangled Qubits with Error correction for 2026+. It would be very interesting in the future to have a paper studying the synergistic effect of maximum Quantum entanglement by comparing the required cooling energy of Quantum computers with 5, 50, 500 and 10k-100k entangled Qubits (once available).

Comment: UPDATE (continued): Why beyond developing quantum computers and related energy cost of cooling, it is worth knowing also for cosmology, whether the required cooling energy increases as Quantum computer processors with more and more entangled Qubits are used, can be read in the Link below dealing with Quantum entanglement, Energy and Geometry of Spacetime. https://www.umwelt-wissenschaft.de/forum/neues-aus-der-wissenschaft-und-forschung/4779-die-grosse-einstein-bohr-debatte-historischer-dokumentarfilm?start=390#113791

Comment: comments are liable to be deleted at any time. Please edit the question to add more details or clarifications